# How To Add A FrameLayout To A ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-framelayout

How can I add a FrameLayout to a ListView?

Comment: @user556163: What is a "frame"?

Comment: Could you post a picture of what you're trying to accomplish? You can certainly return a FrameLayout as a list item from an adapter.

Answer (score 2):

i did like this ..

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/outline" android:layout_height="222dip">
</ListView>
```

....it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Upto my knowledge you cannot add a frame layout to a list view. But you can customise the selector and divider used in the listview.